# With thymeleaf, how to retain original content when th:text evaluates to null?

Tags: thymeleaf

Given this:

```
<span class="template" id="state" th:text="${state}">Your State</span>
```

If there is no value provided for the variable "state", then I want the original tag retained ('`<span class="template" id="state">Your State</span>`') if the @th:text also has to be retained, then that is A-OK.

Is this possible with Thymeleaf and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it by using `#strings.defaultString`

```
<span class="template" id="state"
      th:text="${#strings.defaultString(state,'Your State')}">Your State</span>
```

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping there was an easier way than having to replicate what is already in the HTML content. Thanks!